# kotlin coroutines -block thread until timeout or message count received

Tags: kotlin, coroutine, completable-future

With Kotlin, I would to block a thread until n messages (or a timeout occurs) are received from a callback MessageBroker;

For example -  Something like;

```
fun receivedMessages(numberOfMessages: Int, timeout: Long): List<Message> {
receivedMessages: ArrayList<Message>

//subscribe to a queue and get a callback for EACH message on the queue e.g.

//listen until the 'numberOfMessages' have been reveived OR the timeout is reached. e.g.

async - block
{
    messageQueue.setMessageListener
    (message -> {
    receivedMessages.add(message)
    if (receivedMessages.size > numberOfMessages) //break out of the routine
})

    //else - if timeout is reached - break the routine.
}.withTimeout(timeout)


return receviedMessages
```

}

What is the most eloquent way to do this with kotlin coroutines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much research into coroutines in Kotlin i decided to simply use a `CountdownLatch` and have it countdown until the messageCount has been received; for example;

```
private fun listenForMessages(consumer: MessageConsumer,messageCount: Int, 
                              timeout: Long): List {
    val messages = mutableListOf<T>()
    val outerLatch = CountDownLatch(messageCount)
    consumer.setMessageListener({ it ->
        //do something
        outerLatch.countDown()
    }
})
outerLatch.await(timeout)
return messages
}
```